# Can't create new ubuntu machine in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

For some reason, I suddenly can not create a new Ubuntu machine in VirtualBox. It just gets stuck at this step during OS installation:

[image: 1]

This has never occurred before, not to mention the fact that I still use the same ISO image, which is Ubuntu 20.04.3. I tried using Ubuntu 22.04 and updating VirtualBox but it doesn't work. I'm using Windows 11 home as host.

Comment: Is the Windows 11 machine new?  Did you try turning on Hardware Virtualization (VT-d) in BIOS?

Comment: Okay i manage to fix this by changing the network settings from NAT to bridge adapter and somehow it just works, I don't remember having to do that in previous installations, very weird.

Comment: Networking probably is not the answer. NAT is default and no issue creating a machine with NAT networking

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I try to take the same steps from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROjZy1WbCIA and it works. I did change to NAT but it didnot work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).